# How to Validate an EntityType field?

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4, symfony-validator

I want to make sure that the user chooses an element from the dropdown list.

So I used      `* @Assert\NotBlank()` in the entity file.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Bord::class, inversedBy="cartes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $bord;
```

The problem is it always returns `This value should not be blank.` error on the form! Even when the user selects a value from the list.

I also used `* @Assert\NotNull()` too and I still get the same problem.

I can remove the `Assert` validation and hard code it by testing on the controller and using flash messages! But I want to use Assert Validation.

So How can I validate an EntityType Field?

In the formType:

```
->add('bord',EntityType::class,[
            'class'=>Bord::class,
            'choice_label'=>'ref_bord',
            'label'=>'Bord',
            'placeholder'   =>'Choose a Bord',
            'mapped' => false])
```

On the view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.bord, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}  
{{ form_errors(form.bord) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your entity field not mapped. With `'mapped' => false` the form doesn't put data into the entity, so it is always `null`.